# Bitbucket : is it possible to have one bitbucket-pipelines.yml file per branch?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'd like to have one pipeline per branch

I put one on branch develop and another on branch master but they're no taken into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

But, you don't need to set a different file for each branch. You can  organize pipelines for every and each branch within the same file according to the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html).

The best way to set up your pipelines is defining each step and then calling the steps for each branch you want to.

Don't forget to define the **default** steps (these steps will run for every branch you didn't define previously).

Your bitbucket-pipelines file would look something like this:

```
image: python:3.7.3
definitions:
  steps:   
    - step: &test
        name: Test project
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - apt-get -y update
          - pip install --upgrade pip
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - python -m unittest discover tests

    - step: &lint
        name: Execute linter
        script:
          - pip install flake8
          - chmod a+x ./linter.sh
          - ./linter.sh

    - step: &bump
        name: Bump version
        script:
          - git config remote.origin.url $BITBUCKET_URL_ORIGIN
          - python bump.py

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
    - step: *test
    - step: *lint
    - step: *bump

    develop:
    - step: *test
    - step: *lint

  default:
    - step: *lint
```

Comment: Anchors (`&name` / `*name`) in the YAML are documented here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/